# Can 全部 be used like 「全部の月は忙しいですか？」

Tags: word-choice, set-phrases, phrase-requests

`全部の月は忙しいですか？`

What that is supposed to say is: `Will you be busy all month`?

But I feel that using 全部 in this way might mean all of the months in the year.

So first, when talking about the entirely of a time period can 全部 be used in the way I've shown?

Also, if I wanted to say: `Will you be busy for the rest of the month?` How would word that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [全部]{ぜんぶ} in your context might make sense, but it is not idiomatic.

If you want to ask someone if he will be busy for a month, you could use

> [一ヶ月]{いっカげつ}の[間]{あいだ}ずっと[忙]{いそが}しいですか？ (Literally) For one month continuously busy?

[ずっと](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8) is an adverb that you can use which means:

> continuously in some state, all along, the whole time, etc.

If you want to ask someone if he will be busy for a specific month, for example May, you can use,

> [5月]{ごがつ}[中]{ちゅう}ずっと[忙]{いそが}しいですか？ (Literally) During May continuously busy?

As @Flaw suggested, you can use 月末まで to mean the rest of the month as in:

> [月末]{げつまつ}までずっと[忙]{いそが}しいですか？(Literally) Until the end of this month continuously busy?

Comment: Good answer, but I would like to point out that [一ヶ月]{いっかげつ}[間]{あいだ} should be either [一ヶ月]{いっかげつ}[間]{かん} or [一ヶ月]{いっかげつ}の[間]{あいだ}, and [5月]{ごがつ}[中]{ちゅう}にずっと should be [5月]{ごがつ}[中]{ちゅう}ずっと or [5月]{ごがつ}[中]{ちゅう}はずっと.

Comment: @FailyFeely Great points! I edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can.

I think you'd have to use something like:

- 一月[中]{ちゅう} - all January

For "rest of the month" I think you can use:

- 月末まで

Answer (score 1):

I would say "今月はずっと忙しいですか？"  .